# Item level tracking in Shopify

Tags: shopify

Could you please specify, what is the correct way to track the quantity of the variants of items in stock?

I see that `products/update` webhook shows the quantity, but I'm not sure if it fires when an item is purchased (and its quantity reduces by one), and in case of `inventory_items/update` there's no quantity information (though it seems I can thract it using  `InventoryLevel` API call), but I'm not sure if this notification launches after item purchase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer: Both `products/update` and `inventory_levels/update` are fired when an item is purchased.

The request body of `products/update` looks something like this:

```json
{
  "id": 123,
  "variants": [
    {
      "id": 456,
      "product_id": 123,
      "inventory_quantity": 99
    }
  ]
}
```

`inventory_quantity` is the updated stock of the item that has just been purchased.

On the other hand, the request body of `inventory_levels/update` looks something like this:

```json
{
  "inventory_item_id": 987,
  "available": 99
}
```

So both webhook topics give you access to the data you need. In the end it depends on your specific use case which of those two topics to use.